# Statement.executeQuery() throws java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when executing SELECT command in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, select, jdbc, sqlexception

I have a method that fetches records from MySQL db table using JDBC API. 
The command that I have been using is:

```
"SELECT column_1, column_2, ... FROM table;"
```

The column names are provided to the method in form of ArrayList a query is being constructed based on the column & table names using StringBuilder.

When executing the constructed query using createStatement(), it is throwing: `"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near from $tableName' at line 1"`

This is the full code of the method:

```
public ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> getTableData(String tableName, List<String> selectedParams, int rowCount) {
        try {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select ");
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedParams.size(); i++) {
                query.append(selectedParams.get(i)).append(", ");
            }
            query.append("\b\b from ").append(tableName).append(" limit ").append(rowCount);
            System.out.println("query:" + query);
            ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> rows;
            try (ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery(query.toString())) {
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData();
                rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                while (rset.next()) {
                    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    int count = 1;
                    while (count <= rsmd.getColumnCount()) {
                        row.add(rset.getString(count));
                        count++;
                    }
                    rows.add(row);
                }
            }
            rows.forEach((row) -> {
                System.out.println(row);
            });
            return rows;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When running the code, the generated query form print statement looks something like this:

```
"query:select territory from offices"
```

I have tested this query against db directly and another simple JDBC program and they both run fine. Except for in this method. Please help.

---------------Edit: forgot to paste the exception message:---------------

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near from offices limit 10' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)
```

Comment: Notice that your select list ends with a `,` in the code as shown. That is likely the cause of the problem. Also, why do you have `\b` in your string? That likely doesn't work like you think it does. Try deleting the trailing `,` from the StringBuilder instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to paste the exception message. I have edited the question.
The query doesn't seems to end with a ",". I have used "\b\b" to remove the extra comma and extra space after the last column name has appended to the string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you were right. It was "\b\b" that was creating the issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue id in

```
 for (int i = 0; i < selectedParams.size(); i++) {
                query.append(selectedParams.get(i)).append(", ");
            }
```

the above code will append an extra ',' after param names 
instead you can use

```
query.append(String.join(", ", selectedParams))
```

Comment: This made my spaghetti code lot cleaner. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
query.append("\b\b from ")
```

does *not* remove the trailing comma and space from the StringBuilder. It may *look* like it does when you print it to the console, but the string actually does contain

```
select territory, ␈␈ from offices
```

and MySQL apparently doesn't like that.

Instead, you want to actually *delete* the comma from the StringBuilder (and leave the space):

```
query.deleteCharAt(query.length() - 2).append("from ")
```